How can I determine the power source priority in this LCD controller board?
This board has three power sources, i.e., two USB type C ports and one USB type B micro. I use one of the type C ports for power and data and the display works well, however, I need to design a power source - a battery with a charging system to avoid pulling power from the host device.
My problem is that I cannot tell which power source the board will draw power from if I supply power via any of the other ports.
I have checked on the host device USB info(on Mac OS System Profile) and it does not display the current being drawn.


There's some minimal info on the seller's page.

what is preventing you from determining the answer experimentally?

Kindly drop some hints on this.

measure the current

Added a multimeter in series and it turned out that the first power supply is maintained even if an extra one is added, and switches to the next[available] power supply when the initial is detached.
